# javascript generated form with cancel

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html table with an Edit button.  Clicking "Edit" builds a form with javascript.  I'm using jquery to hide the row with "Edit".  Now I'm trying to get the Cancel button to work with this.  Where if you click "Cancel" it puts the row in the table back (which is easy) but it also hides the form.

I'm not sure how to hide the form.  I've create an jsfiddle which has all the details:
http://jsfiddle.net/h34Hr/13/

Press "Edit" on any row then press "Cancel" in the form.  It does bring the row back but I'm not sure how to hide the form.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn't it be MUCH easier to have form statically created in HTML, and on "edit" simply populate the field values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should utilise JQuery a bit more.

To fix your issue try changing this

```
myCancel.onclick = function() { 
    thisrow.show();
};
```

to this

```
myCancel.onclick = function() { 
    thisrow.show();
    $('#editform').hide();
};
```

Comment: Thanks, that works but only one time.  Now if you go back to another row to edit or the same row the form doesn't show up anymore and rows start disappearing...any ideas?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, didnt test it properly :)
If you swap `$('#editform').hide()` for `document.getElementById('editform').innerHTML = "";` it should work. As you're basically recreating the form every time the edit button is clicked it makes sense just to remove the contents when you close it.